# How used DIVIDE with a CONDENSED NUMERIC Varibale in COBOL

Tags: cobol

My problem is: I have data in a database table. The column is: `Z-ZYTL-RTPDHR` defined as `NOT NULL NUMBER(5,2)` .

So I have a program that I need to move my data in one variable "H-ZYTL-RTPDHR" and after I will move this value divide by 100 in one column Z8 when i compile i obtained Excel with data in the different column.

My data:

```
Z8
------
34,28
70
97
8,57
21,43
94,28
94,28
100
40
40
```

what I should get:

```
Z8
-------
0,3428
0,7
0,97
0,0857
0,2143
0,9428
0,9428
0,100
0,40
0,40
```

my question how to declare the variable to obtain the good result?

Variables that I declared:

```
        01  FILLER.
         05  H-ZYTL-RTPDHR.
          10 PIC S9(5)V9(2) comp-3 VALUE.
         05  FILLER REDEFINES  H-ZYTL-RTPDHR.
          10      H-ZYTL-RTPDHR        comp-3 pic s9(5)v99.
```

Equivalent Temps Plein

```
        05  W-Z8                   PIC -(5),99.
        05  FILLER                 PIC X(001) VALUE ';'.

   ALIM-WZ8 SECTION.

          IF Z-ZYTL-NOMBRE > ZERO
              IF TLCODTRA(Z-ZYTL-NOMBRE) NOT = SPACES
                 MOVE Z-ZYTL-RTPDHR(Z-ZYTL-NOMBRE) TO
                     H-ZYTL-RTPDHR
                DISPLAY 'H-ZYTL-RTPDHR:'  H-ZYTL-RTPDHR
                  DIVIDE H-ZYTL-RTPDHR  BY 100   GIVING W-Z8
               DISPLAY 'W-Z8 : ' W-Z8
              END-IF
           END-IF.
```

Comment: If you want to divide 34,28 by 100 and get 0,3428 then you need to change the definition of W-Z8.

At the moment, W-Z8 only supports two decimal places so you would get 0,34.

W-Z8 should perhaps by PIC -(3),9999 as you are going to be dividing by 100.

Comment: Yes , but how i should declared my first variable ?

Comment: So your initial data in the database is NUMBER(5,2) so that is five digits and two decimal places. 

So your first variable should be something like David Gorsline said. Try something like 01 H-ZYTL-RTPDHR PIC S9(5)V99 PACKED-DECIMAL.

Then the target variable needs to have more decimal places, so

01 W-Z8 PIC -(3),9999.

Comment: I do like this 01  FILLER.
    10      H-ZYTL-RTPDHR        comp-3 pic s9(5)v99.   and  so 01 W-Z8 PIC -(3),9999.  and its work now , thanks alot

Comment: Can you upvote my comments if they were helpful?

Comment: But if i need only 2 decimales like 23,445 i want only 0,23 or 9,53 i obtain 0,95 its possible ?

Comment: i do it i used only -(3),99. yes u help me thanks

Comment: how can i upvote ur comments ?

Comment: There should be a triangle to the left of my comment, above the "flag" icon.

Comment: @James - The `-(3),9999` does not quite fit the examples given. It should be `-(3)9,9999` because zero is shown before the decimal-point.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, Rick. I'll have a look. I think PIC -9(3),9999 is correct, and PIC S9(5)V99 for the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the name `H-ZYTL-RTPDHR` twice: that will confuse you and and the compiler as well.

Your second definition of `H-ZYTL-RTPDHR` is good for doing arithmetic.  All you need is

```
01  FILLER.
    10      H-ZYTL-RTPDHR        comp-3 pic s9(5)v99.
```

Your first definition of `H-ZYTL-RTPDHR` defines a [group level item](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQ2R2_14.1.0/com.ibm.ent.cbl.zos.doc/PGandLR/tasks/tpbeg04b.html), and you can't do arithmetic with it.

However, your question doesn't show the definition of `Z-ZYTL-RTPDHR`.  If it's not numeric, then you won't get the results you expect.

Comment: My Z-ZYTL-RTPDHR is number not null (5,2) like 100,00 ; 90,90 .... and how i shoud declare my 2 variable to obtain the right resultat like what i put above

Comment: HI , i have another probleme with the same thinks , that now i have alot of space  like : if i have 21,12 ; 1223,55 i will get  21,12 but with 9 space in the left i was declared my  varibale 05  H-ZYSR-MONTAN           PIC S9(11)V9(2) COMP-3. and after  05  W-Z18                  PIC -(12),99.
            05  FILLER                 PIC X(001) VALUE ';'.

and i do my program :

Comment: Ask another question, rather than adding a comment.  Please include all of the relevant WORKING-STORAGE SECTION and PROCEDURE DIVISION code.